# PNGs half-rendering with PhantomJS and node phantom module?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm running into an issue using PhantomJS and [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) to render a webpage to a PDF.

What I'm noticing is that, while SVG and JPGs load "fully" into the generated PDF, PNG images do not, *but only on their first appearance in the document*. In other words, the first image is partially faded, then the subsequent images are not faded at all.

I've checked the `onResourceLoaded` callback, and the images are loading properly from the server. I've tried swapping http and https to see if that made a difference. Tried loading from a local, static folder to see if it was a network delay. And I've tried wrapping `page.render` in a `setTimeout` (as many suggest on SO in other questions) to no avail.

Is this a known issue? Is there a better workaround to solve the faded out PNG? Unfortunately, in this project, I don't have control over what image type comes into me.

Comment: Can you provide an example (image) of what you mean by "faded"? Is it only partially loaded (e.g. only the top)? Blurry? Or actually faded (as if there was an opacity setting)? Is this specific to a single website, or does it happen on all sites? Can you provide the URL of the page you're capturing?

Comment: Sorry, its not live yet, as I'm testing a possible feature for future use - so no URL. However, here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/0R1svN5) of what is happening. To what you said, it's as if the opacity has been set to `0.5` or something on the first instance.

Comment: Does the site actually use opacity somehow? E.g. while loading the image, or as an animation once loaded?

Comment: No. I've written it specifically to be rendered into a PDF, so its very bare bones styling. No transitions, animations or the like.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different PhantomJS version? Try to upgrade or downgrade. PhantomJS 1.x is comparable to Chrome 13. If you're using some kind of CSS that is not supported by PhantomJS this might lead to undefined behavior. What happens if you render it as JPG or PNG?

Comment: Tried with 1.9.8 and 2.0.0 - same issue.

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we could use to reproduce the issue. That would include both a source page and rendering code.

Comment: [Here's a jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zojesu/edit?html,css,js,output) with my code.. it's WIP, so please pardon the mess. The CSS is for print-only, so in-browser styling will be off.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue and accidentally discovered that forcing a border color on all elements fixed the issue. In my case, the affected/faded elements were images (jpg) and charts.

So, something like

```css
* {
    border-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try that. My current fix is loading them all inside 1x1 pixel boxes, making subsequent uses full-res. My issue is with PNG files, however.

Comment: i guess nature... uh... finds a way. This actually worked! I was able to use any colour - so long as it wasn't semi transparent.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs with JPGs as well. I've encountered this issue converting HTML files to PDF using both **PhantomJS** (through the **html-pdf** package) and through **wkhtmltopdf**.

With PhantomJS, I noticed the issue was related to use of transparent colours using `rgba()` in borders in other elements. I simply replaced those transparent colours with HEX codes, and the transparency issue has disappeared.

In short, remove any `rgba()` expressions, particularly if they use transparency.